# Socket.IO flashsocket security sandbox error

Tags: socket.io, cross-domain-policy, flashsocket

I have been playing around with node.js and socket.io for the past few days. Everything works fine on my local machine (windows using iss for a webserver), but when uploading it to my remote server (ubuntu box), I get security errors.

```
[trace] Warning: Failed to load policy file from http://localhost:8000/crossdomain.xml
[trace] *** Security Sandbox Violation ***
[trace] Connection to http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/ halted - not permitted from http://****/virtualcinema/VirtualCinema.swf
[trace] Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security sandbox violation: http://****/virtualcinema/VirtualCinema.swf cannot load data from http://localhost:8000/socket.io/1/.
```

The AS3 code it's erroring on is:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://localhost:10843");
socket = new FlashSocket("localhost:8000");
```

The policy file is being served correctly on port 10843 and I can receive the policy file fine at http://****:10843/ in my browser. Why is it trying to load the policy file on port 8000. That warning does not appear on my local build.

The socket.io code:

```
socket = io.listen(8000);

socket.configure(function() 
{
    socket.set("transports", ["flashsocket"]);
    socket.set("log level", 2);

});
```

I'm confused as to why it gets resolved fine when I test it on a localmachine but not on a remote one. Any help would be much appreciated :)

The crossdomain.xml I am using:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: The problem is that instead of loading the policy file from xmlsocket://localhost:10843, it loads it from http://localhost:8000/crossdomain.xml which returns "Welcome to socket.io." as that is the port my server is running on.

Comment: Quick question, are you using a library to talk to your socket.io server from as3 or are you using As3's socket/xmlsockets?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I changed it from pointing to localhost to my servers externalIP.

I had tried this before, but unfortunately the server had cached my swf file and I did not realise it was fixed.

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("xmlsocket://****.com:10843");
socket = new FlashSocket("****.com:8000");
```